# PHP Script to transfer files from one ftp to another ftp

Tags: php, ftp

I want run a php script on a server where are no files to transfer. This script should transfer files from one ftp (with password) to another ftp (with password).
It is possible in php?
ftp_fput allows only to transfer a local file to a ftp-server? Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [thephpleague](https://thephpleague.com/)'s [Flysystem](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/) [FTP adapter](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/adapter/ftp/). You can create a script based on this package and use it on your ***control server*** in order to transfer files from ***ftp server A*** to ***ftp server B***.

Here is an example script that transfer data from ***server A*** to ***server B*** using ***sftp***. ***NOTE***: The following script assumes you have installed the flysystem package (e.g. `composer require league/flysystem`).

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Sftp\SftpAdapter;

$source = new Filesystem(new SftpAdapter([
    'host' => 'server A',
    'port' => 'server A port',
    'username' => 'server A sftp user',
    'password' => 'server A sftp pwd',
    'root' => 'source folder on server A',
    'timeout' => 10,
]));

$destination = new Filesystem(new SftpAdapter([
    'host' => 'server B',
    'port' => 'server B port',
    'username' => 'server B sftp user',
    'password' => 'server B sftp pwd',
    'root' => 'destination folder on server B',
    'timeout' => 10,
]));

$files = $source->listContents();

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $data = $source->read($file['path']);
    $destination->put($file['path'], $data);
}
```

It establishes a connection to the source (`$source`) and the destination (`$destination`) servers. List the contents on the source (`listContents()` method) and in a `foreach` loop it reads the files (`read()`) and put their content (`put()`) to the desired place one by one.